# If $X\neq\varnothing$ and $\tau=\{\varnothing, X\}$, then any subset of $X$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> If $X\neq\varnothing$ and $\tau=\{\varnothing, X\}$, then any subset of $X$ is compact.

Disproof by counterxample? Not true. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and $A = (-\infty,0)$. Clearly $A$ is not compact.

EDIT: Thank you to those below who provided their criticism and feedback.

Here is my new attempt

Let $A \subset X$ and $\{G_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in a}$ be an open cover of A.

Since $\emptyset$, $X$ are the only open sets in $\tau$, $G_{\alpha} = X \cup \emptyset = X$

As a result, there is a finite subcover of $A$, hence $A$ is compact

Therefore, any subset of $X$ is compact.

Comment: Try proving more generally that if $\tau$ is finite, then any subset of $X$ is compact.

Comment: The question is not about $A$ being compact, or any subset of $X$, but about $X$ itself.

Comment: Careful with your quantifiers. It is not necessarily true that $G_\alpha=X$ for all $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Compactness is something relative to the topology.

You are given a topology on $X$, namely $\tau=\{\varnothing,X\}$. And the claim is that every subset of $X$ is compact in *that* topology.

So your counterexample is not a counterexample, since it doesn't uses the given topology.

Comment: Oh, of course! A is not open - how could I miss that? :D

Comment: Note that open sets can be compact in some topologies. The implication "compact$\implies$closed" is true for Hausdorff spaces, but not in general.

Comment: @Aida:  The fact that $A$ is not open is irrelevant.  If you expand  the topology to $\tau=\{\emptyset ,A,X\}$, then $A$ is open, but it's still compact.

Comment: @AsafKaragila also you can still have a compact open set in a Hausdorff space, e.g. $[0,1]$ with the subspace topology is a compact clopen set.

Comment: @DanZimm: Of course, but it's also closed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on definition. It may be:

1. $X$ is compact if each of its open covers has a finite subcover.

or

2. $X$ is compact if it is Hausdorff ($T_2$) and each of its open covers has a finite subcover.

There is only one nonempty open set, hence $X$ is compact in the sense of 1.

But even if $X=\{0,1\}$ with the topology in question, it is not Hausdorff, hence is not compact in the sense of 2.

Comment: Clearly Hausdorffness is not part of the definition in this case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Clearly "clearly" have been overused here, hence clearly we should wait for OP's definition, especially because she suggests disproving.

Comment: Where did you get definition 2)? Never seen before. Definition 1) is standard.

Comment: @drhab Ryszard Engelking, General Topology. Probably the best book on topology. One chapter is about different variant of compatness. And even Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space gives two versions.

Comment: Thank you. The more I know about mathematics the more I realize that I know (almost) nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Can there be an open cover of $A\subset X$ that is not finite?